# Why I have to update inner state through the useEffect hook in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Perhaps I got a wrong understanding of react flow, but can someone explain this magic :)

Why I have to update inner state through the useEffect hook in React?

I thought the component updating will trigger rewriting the initial state of useState hook.

```
  const [list, setList] = useState<TabItem[]>(tabs);

  useEffect(() => {
    setList(tabs);
  }, [tabs]);
```

Comment: What is "inner state"? The initial state is only referenced once when state is instantiated, separate from everything else. The `useEffect` in this example will run *after* state has been instantiated and the component rendered out, and you don't need a `useEffect` hook to update state, you can invoke the state updater anywhere. Your question isn't very clear. Perhaps you could include a more comprehensive code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is when React re-renders the functional component , state hook `React.useState(tabs)` is not executed again.

That's why the previous state persists through the next render cycle.

So, in order for your props to derive into your inner state, you can provide the `tabs` props inside a `React.useEffect()` hook so that the useEffect callback will run again and set the state again with `setList(tabs)`.